# How to take backup of Windows files on dual boot and then I can completely allocate the disk space to Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, partitioning, boot-partition

First I had Windows 10 on my laptop's hard drive. Then I dual booted with Ubuntu because of the slow speed of my laptop, and then Windows 10 was giving problems. After a few days I bought an SSD and installed Ubuntu 22.04 on it, but now the same laptop has 3 OSs, 2 in HDD and 1 in SSD.

Now the SSD is my priority and I want completely delete the old Windows 10 and Ubuntu partitions on the HDD and take a backup of this operating system.

GParted:

[image: GParted showing disk partitions]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Make a complete backup of your partitions or hdd with `dd`.

`sudo dd if=/dev/sda conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c  > /PATH/TO/YOUR/DRIVE/backup_image.img.gz`

The arguments above are as follows.

- `bs`: Set the block size for copy (the default is 512 bytes but doesn’t work well for larger drives)
- `noerror`:  Instructs dd to continue operation, ignoring all read errors
- `sync`: Instruct dd to fill input blocks with zeroes if there were any read errors
- `status`: for some progress infos while the dd process is running

Restoring the compressed backup with `gunzip -c /PATH/TO/DRIVE/backup_image.img.gz | dd of=/dev/sda`

Hope this helps...

You could use other Imaging tools as well of course :)

Comment: Hrm `of=/dev/sdb1` is most likely not be what you intended here, especially as you have a pipe to gzip.

Comment: you are correct sorry :D - edited